# Recent issue with Chrome where screen rendering fails when scrolling on long page

Tags: google-chrome

Our application has been using Chrome without a problem for years. In the last three weeks, at least in Chrome 85, we have had numerous reports of full width bands at the top, bottom or in the middle of the screen disappearing when a long web page is scrolled quickly. These bands are permanent until the mouse is moved when part of all of the missing page gradually reappears, mostly in the area of the cursor. This is very frustrating for our users, I can see no similar reports from other Chrome users but this must be a browser issue. I have attached two screenshots of the problem which we can easily recreate. Any help appreciated.

[Screenshot showing missing band mid way in long page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3BpV.jpg)

[Screenshot showing partial repaint which continues as mouse is moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdyQ1.jpg)

Comment: We are also seeing this issue in the Chromium based  Microsoft Edge browser

Answer (score 0):

I have used Chrome Canary to test this issue in V87 and it now seems to be fixed. It also seems to be fixed in the latest Chromium based Edge version.